# Python - Mocking chained function calls

Tags: python, mocking, chained

I have the following statement in one of the methods under unit test.

```
db_employees = self.db._session.query(Employee).filter(Employee.dept ==   
    new_employee.dept).all()
```

I want db_employees to get mock list of employees. I tried to achieve this using:

```
 m = MagickMock()
 m.return_value.filter().all().return_value = employees
```

where employees is a list of employee object. But this did not work. When I try to print the value of any attribute, it has a mock value. This is how the code looks:

```
class Database(object):
    def __init__(self, user=None, passwd=None, db="sqlite:////tmp/emp.db"):
        try:
            engine = create_engine(db)
        except Exception:
            raise ValueError("Database '%s' does not exist." % db)

        def on_connect(conn, record):
            conn.execute('pragma foreign_keys=ON')

        if 'sqlite://' in db:
            event.listen(engine, 'connect', on_connect)
        Base.metadata.bind = engine
        DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        self._session = DBSession()


class TestEmployee(MyEmployee):
    def setUp(self):
        self.db = emp.database.Database(db=options.connection)
        self.db._session._autoflush()

    @mock.patch.object(session.Session, 'add')     
    @mock.patch.object(session.Session, 'query')  
    def test_update(self, mock_query, mock_add):
        employees = [{'id': 1,
                      'name': 'Pradeep',
                      'department': 'IT',
                      'manager': 'John'}]
        mock_add.side_effect = self.add_side_effect
        mock_query.return_value = self.query_results()  
        self.update_employees(employees)

    def add_side_effect(self, instance, _warn=True):
        // Code to mock add
        // Values will be stored in a dict which will be used to 
        // check with expected value.

    def query_results(self):  
        m = MagicMock()  
        if self.count == 0:  
             m.return_value.filter.return_value.all.return_value = [employee]  
        elif:  
             m.return_value.filter.return_value.all.return_value = [department]  
        return m
```

I have query_results as the method under test calls query twice. First the employee table and next the department table.

How do I mock this chained function call?

Comment: First of all replace `m.return_value.filter...` by `m.filter...` because `m` is already set as `query` return value. And the add to your question that `mock_query.mock_calls` is empty. As far as I can understand you are patching the wrong object.

Comment: Now try to use `@mock.patch(__name__ + '.DBSession.query')` to patch query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should patch `query()` method of `_session`'s `Database` attribute and configure it to give you the right answer. You can do it in a lot of way, but IMHO the cleaner way is to patch `DBSession`'s `query` static reference. I don't know from witch module you imported `DBSession` so I'll patch the local reference.

The other aspect is the mock configuration: we will set `query`'s return value that in your case become the object that have `filter()` method.

```
class TestEmployee(MyEmployee):
    def setUp(self):
        self.db = emp.database.Database(db=options.connection)
        self.db._session._autoflush()
        self.log_add = {}

    @mock.patch.object(__name__.'DBSession.add')     
    @mock.patch.object(__name__.'DBSession.query')  
    def test_update(self, mock_query, mock_add):
        employees = [{'id': 1,
                      'name': 'Pradeep',
                      'department': 'IT',
                      'manager': 'John'}]
        mock_add.side_effect = self.add_side_effect
        mock_query.return_value = self.query_results()  
        self.update_employees(employees)
        .... your test here

    def add_side_effect(self, instance, _warn=True):
        # ... storing data
        self.log_add[...] = [...]

    def query_results(self):  
        m = MagicMock()
        value = "[department]"
        if not self.count:  
             value = "[employee]"  
        m.filter.return_value.all.return_value = value 
        return m
```

Comment: It worked. Changed mock_query.return_value to mock_query.side_effect = self.query_results. Now I am able to get the objects as expected. I am accepting your answer, as it helped me to resolve the chained function call.

Answer (score 45):

```
m = Mock()
m.session.query().filter().all.return_value = employees
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Comment: Ah, this is brilliant -- we had been creating the results of chained methods manually, eg. `obj = Mock(); Object = Mock(); Object.return_value = obj` but this stopped working once there were was more than 1 level of chaining, and the `package.one().two().three().return_value = ...` is all that worked

Comment: How do you get around `Expected 'filter' to have been called once. Called 2 times.` when doing something like `m.session.query.assert_called_once()`?

Comment: This makes your test dependent on implementation details and quite brittle... is there really not a better way?

Comment: This will add to the call stack for the mock. You can get around that by using the return_values instead: `m.session.query.return_value.filter.return_value.all.return_value = employees`

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution to a similar problem where I needed to mock out a nested set of filtering calls.

Given code under test similar to the following:

```
interesting_cats = (session.query(Cats)
                           .filter(Cat.fur_type == 'furry')
                           .filter(Cat.voice == 'meowrific')
                           .filter(Cat.color == 'orande')
                           .all())
```

You can setup mocks like the following:

```
mock_session_response = MagicMock()
# This is the magic - create a mock loop
mock_session_response.filter.return_value = mock_session_response
# We can exit the loop with a call to 'all'
mock_session_response.all.return_value = provided_cats

mock_session = MagicMock(spec=Session)
mock_session.query.return_value = mock_session_response
```